# Docker awslogs gives error NoCredentialProviders

Tags: linux, docker, amazon-cloudwatch

**Problem**

I'm trying to send docker logs to Aws Cloudwatch using my **on premise server** but it keeps failing on authentication. I've spent tons of hours searching through documentation and tutorials - and yet it does not work.

**Approach**

I've installed AWS-cli and configured it, so ~/.aws/config is filled with my credentials. I've also set temporarily the session-variables just to be safe:

```
EXPORT AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=...
EXPORT AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=...
EXPORT AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=...
```

I've verified I can connect to AWS using:

```
aws s3 ls
```

This is my run config:

```
docker run --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-group=docker-logs --log-opt awslogs-region=eu-west-1 --log-opt awslogs-create-group=true alpine echo 'hi cloudwatch'
```

When tailing /var/log/daemon.log I see the following error:

```
Feb 1 01:12:07 XXXXXX dockerd[7389]: time="2021-02-01T01:12:07.670370559+01:00" level=error msg="Failed to create log stream" errorCode=NoCredentialProviders logGroupName=docker-logs logStreamName=61c82801d22d3db4c68cdc5b3d1dcba51f97c77dea5ce33e262b712c0e2a23a7 message="no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.\n\tFor verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors" origError=""
```

I've also tried giving docker run the session-variables as --ENV-parameters. Still doesn't work.
I've also tried insert the EXPORT'ed variables into /etc/default/docker. Still no luck.

Docker has no problem uploading to cloudwatch if I run with log-driver="json-file" and point to a file. So it's only awslogs giving problems.

**Versions**

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.1.22 Python/3.7.3 Linux/4.19.57-v7l+ source/armv7l.raspbian.10 prompt/off
```

```
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.2, build 2291f61
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was facing similar kind of issue on ubuntu 18 instance.
Following are the steps which worked for me:

1. mkdir -p /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/
2. touch /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/aws-credentials.conf
3. vi /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/aws-credentials.conf
   content of file as follows:
   [Service]
   Environment="AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="
   Environment="AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="
4. sudo systemctl daemon-reload
5. sudo service docker restart

Comment: Good find! Accepted as solution!