# Where do I put `.aws/credentials` for Docker awslogs log-driver (and avoid NoCredentialProviders)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

The [Docker awslogs documentation](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/awslogs/#credentials) states:

> the default AWS shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials of the root user)

Yet if I copy my AWS `credentials` file there:

```bash
sudo bash -c 'mkdir -p $HOME/.aws; cp .aws/credentials $HOME/.aws/credentials'
```

... and then try to use the driver:

```bash
docker run --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-group=neiltest-deleteme --rm hello-world
```

The result is still the dreaded error:

> docker: Error response from daemon: failed to initialize logging driver: failed to create Cloudwatch log stream: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
> For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors.

Where does this file *really* need to go? Is it because the Docker daemon isn't running as root but rather some other user and, if so, how do I determine that user?

NOTE:  I can work around this on systems using systemd by [setting environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65991844/docker-awslogs-gives-error-nocredentialproviders). But this doesn't work on Google CloudShell where the Docker daemon has been started by some other method.

Comment: Are you using ECS?

Comment: @Marcin: Not using ECS; for that and EC2 I would simply configure an EC2 IAM Role. For this Question I'm specifically interested in knowing where to put the `.aws/credentials` file for Docker awslogs to be able to use it.

Comment: It must be in your container, not the host in that case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha! I figured it out and tested this on Debian Linux (on my Chromebook w/ Linux VM and Google CloudShell):

**The .aws folder must be in the *root* folder of the *root* user *not* in the `$HOME` folder!**

Based on that I was able to successfully run the following:

```
pushd $HOME; sudo bash -c 'mkdir -p /.aws; cp .aws/* /.aws/'; popd
docker run --log-driver=awslogs --log-opt awslogs-region=us-east-1 --log-opt awslogs-group=neiltest-deleteme --rm hello-world
```

I initially figured this all out by looking at the Docker daemon's process information:

```
DOCKERD_PID=$(ps -A | grep dockerd | grep -Eo '[0-9]+' | head -n 1)
sudo cat /proc/$DOCKERD_PID/environ
```

The confusing bit is that Docker's documentation here is wrong:

> the default AWS shared credentials file (~/.aws/credentials of the root user)

The true location is `/.aws/credentials`. I believe this is because the daemon starts before `$HOME` is actually defined since it's not running as a user process. So starting a shell as root will tell you a different story for tilde or `$HOME`:

```
sudo sh -c 'cd ~/; echo $PWD'
```

That outputs `/root` but using `/root/.aws/credentials` **does not work!**